Разница реализации между статическим методом и методом экземпляра
Описание
Немного абстрактный вопрос, решение которого я не могу точно найти уже долгое время.
У вас есть класс для работы с координатами, который включает метод расчета дистанции между двумя точками:
class Point2D {
  static getDistanceBetween(point1: Point2D, point2: Point2D): number {
    return Math.hypot(point1.x - point2.x, point1.y - point2.y);
  }
  getDistanceFrom(other: Point2D): number {
    return Point2D.getDistanceBetween(this, other);
  }
}

Вопрос
Правильно ли иметь этот метод как статический и как метод экземпляра?
Применимо ли это к другим методам, например, к методу клонирования?
Насколько это логично?
Насколько оптимизировано?

В общем я бы хотел, чтобы вы сказали все сильные и слабые стороны данного контекста и как бы вы посоветовали поступить в подобных ситуациях.
Дополнительно
Вопрос подписал как typescript, но язык в данном контексте имеет очень малую разницу.

Как по мне, так метод экземпляра должен работать с данными самого экземпляра + какие-то параметры... Метод класса работает только со своими параметрами.

Иметь статический метод работающий с двумя точками и метод экземпляра, который работает со "своей" точкой и той, что дали в параметрах - вполне нормально. Типа расширяет возможности, сервис... Про "остальные" - смотря как ты это все организуешь.

@ksa ну к примеру toString практически везде прикреплен к экземпляру, но вот parse прикреплен к классу. Ещё пример - для большинства классов я создаю методы import и export которые собирают из анонимного объекта экземпляр класса и обратное. Class.import обязательно должен быть статическим, но каким должен быть export?

@ksa таких множество примеров есть, и я хочу найти какое-нибудь логичное объяснение - почему стоит делать статичным и почему нет.

я хочу найти какое-нибудь логичное объяснение логичное объяснение я дал тебе в первом комментарии...

@ksa Я учел вашу точку зрения, спасибо.
